# How dynamic cast is working between two classes which has common derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

In below code I have Derived1 class which is derived from two classes/struct (I1 and Base). Using this relation I am able to dynamic cast Base type pointer to I1 type. Which I could not understand in terms in Vtable. Can someone explain, how did this work (in terms of Vtable).

```
 struct Base
 {    
    virtual ~Base() {};
 };

 struct I1
 { 
     virtual void f1() = 0;
 };

//---------------------------------------------
struct Derived1 : public Base, public I1 
{
    void f1() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

//---------------------
Base* getBase()
{
    return new Derived1;
}

int main()
{

    Base* base = getBase();
```

I did not understand how this below dynamic cast worked when there is no parent chid relation between below two classes. How did this work?

```
    I1* i1 = dynamic_cast<I1*>(base);    
    i1->f1();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This presentation from CppCon2017 by Arthur O'Dwyer gives a nice overview for one way to do it: https://youtu.be/QzJL-8WbpuU.

Comment: Clear examples on dynamic cast: 
  https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/dynamic_cast.php

Comment: It's a bit underhanded that `getBase()` returns actually an instance of `Derived1`. Although `Base` is not related to `I1`, the returned instance is of type `Derived1`. Hence, the `dynamic_cast<I1*>` is possible and results in a non-`nullptr`. (I must admit that I hadn't relied on this fact in my code. Multiple inheritance is still a bit scaring to me.) ;-)

Comment: Capsule summary: there's a separate vtable for each instance of a class that's a part of the "most derived class". The compiler creates more than one vtable for `Base`, one gets created for each most derived class that ultimately inherits from it. Same is true for all intermediate classes. Each class instance, and all of its superclasses, get linked to the correct vtable. Each vtable includes a link to the vtable for the most derived class. The End.